# sed command to replace pattern&(\n) not working Terminal

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, terminal

Trying to replace a specific pattern ending with a "\n" line break and can't seem to figure it out. But I need to be able to pipe the result to another command and it's not in a file.

Example:

```
$echo "test
some text testing
test
some text testing
test" | sed 's/ testing\n/|/g' | (more commands)
```

Expected result would be:

```
test
some text|test
some text|test
```

Comment: This is the task for multiline sed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "test
some text testing
test
some text testing
test" | sed '/testing/{N;s/ testing\n/|/;}'
```

We look for lines matching `/testing/` in our pattern space and append the next line to pattern space using `N`. The two lines are separated by `\n`. We then proceed with a simple substitution of removing `testing\n` and replacing it with `|`.

Comment: Getting an error trying that...: `bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: @double_j Looks like you are on a Mac. Place a `;` before `}`. `sed '/testing/{N;s/ testing\n*/|/g;}'`. BSD `sed` requires a `;` before `}`.

Comment: @double_j The above code works for me , i just copied and pasted it in the terminal ,

Comment: @Ram GNU `sed` won't complain. BSD `sed` will.

Comment: @Ram This does work with that `;` in there! I'm just curious as to how it works this way and why I need the pattern in there twice?

Comment: @double_j Check Update. First pattern is to isolate the line. Second pattern is to remove the portion you dont need. Ram, I added some explanation to your answer. If you feel it has radically changed it please go ahead and revert it.

Comment: @jaypal That explains it! Thanks a bunch guys

Comment: @jaypal Thanks a lot for making the answer better , i was about to add an explanation , this was exactly what i had in mind .

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to other suggestions, you could use a Perl one-liner using your pattern.

```
$ echo "test
> some text testing
> test
> some text testing
> test" | perl -pe 's/ testing\n/|/g'

test
some text|test
some text|test
```

Comment: I went with @ram answer because he's still using `sed` but I like this method too and may ending using it elsewhere, Thanks!